# Headless/CLI LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm coding the server-side for a small LibGDX powered game, and have stumbled across an issue. Every time I try and use any `Gdx.files.*` methods, I'm met with a `NullPointerException`.

Apparently this is because I'm not implementing the ApplicationListener, so LibGDX has not been initialized.

Is there any way of initializing LibGDX in a headless/CLI way? I need to be able to load TiledMap objects on the server-side.

```
MapLoader(Request request)
{
    TiledMap tmp = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/" + request.name + ".tmx");
}
```

> Exception in thread "Server" java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.tester.Example.server.ExampleServer$2.received(MapLoader.java:83)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server$1.received(Server.java:60)   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection.notifyReceived(Connection.java:246)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server.update(Server.java:202)  at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server.run(Server.java:350)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: I am running into a related problem trying to use TiledMaps on my headless backend.  Did you ever discover a way to make use of the map loader on your server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>I would not recommend using libGDX for a headless environment, it was simply not designed to be used that way and you may encounter issues in the future as the libGDX team changes the framework.</s> However, as Rod pointed out, it is entirely possible to do so and below is a snippet of how you would go about it. To initialize the Gdx.files global you will need to create a class in the backend package and setup the globals yourself:

```
package com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class Headless {
    public static void loadHeadless() {
        LwjglNativesLoader.load();
        Gdx.files = new LwjglFiles();
    }
}
```

The rest should be fairly simple. Just call Headless.loadHeadless(); at the start and then you should be able to use parts of the framework you require.

As I stated before, I would not suggest doing this, but I haven't found any nice solutions for using libgdx with a client/server architecture.

**Edit**:

A little while back (after I wrote this answer originally) libgdx added a [headless backend](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends/gdx-backend-headless) which is designed for this kind of purpose. It is the correct and proper way to use libgdx in a headless environment and works very well for creating a server with libgdx.

Answer (score 6):

As of Dec 23, 2013 ([pull request #1018](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/dd977b08a9bc5eba21031cb450581146dea1a01f)), libGDX has a [headless backend](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends/gdx-backend-headless) that you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the LWJGL back end, specifically [LwjglApplication.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplication.java). The constructor for *LwjglApplication* initializes all of the *Gdx.** globals such as *Gdx.files*.

If you were to invoke the steps run in the constructor from your own code, except for the call to *initialize()*, then that should get you what you want.