# Is it possible to use libgdx without an ApplicationListener?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to use libgdx in an application merely for its cross-plattform audio support, not to develop a game. I naively just tried to load a sound and play it but it seems that some initialisation of the engine has to take place as all members of the Gdx class (e.g. "files") are empty.

Is there a way for me to either manually initialize the Gdx context or just to load a Sound (e.g. via a call to SoundLoader.loadSync) or is this unsupported?

Comment: Currently, there is no such way. LibGDX gets initialized by creating an `Application` (for example a [`LwjglApplication`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplication.java)), which needs an `ApplicationListener`. You might try to initialize the "subsystems" yourself though, by executing the platform specific code of the `Application`s.

Comment: Too bad. I was hoping to get around platform-specific stuff here as I am targeting multiple platforms and had hoped for some kind of platform-independent "init-gdx-environment" code. Is there maybe some way to make a libgdx application headless as a workaround?

Comment: I hadn't looked for the term headless before and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068468/headless-cli-libgdx. I was able to get it to work now with this code: 
        LwjglNativesLoader.load();
        Gdx.files = new LwjglFiles();
        Gdx.audio = new OpenALAudio();